# Stop Excel from changing comma to semicolon in VBA made formula

Tags: vba, excel

Decimal numbers (in our regional settings, a comma is the decimal symbol) are changed to semicolons when used in formula.

Let's say I have a number (I actually just parse it from a field but I need it in a variable):

> c = 10,5

If I do:

> sheet.Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUM(" & c & ",10)"

The whole formula becomes:

> =SUM(10;5;10)

The comma is always changed to a semi-colon which ruins the double number.
I can use *.FormulaLocal* and then the semi-colon separator works in the formula but the comma still works too so that does not solve it.

Changing the regional settings does not work since I need to distribute it and won't be able to get everyone to change the regional settings.

Anything that could save me from this?

Comment: What is the type of `c`? Do you need to keep the `Sum` formula (I guess yes) or could you simply use `sheet.Cells(1,1).Value = c + 10`?

Comment: Just to get it straight - with your regional settings 10,5 is 10 and a half and the formula should be  `=SUM(10 and a half;10)` - but VBA is determined to be American and keeps converting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if c i as string containing a double value in local format, you can use:

```
sheet.Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUM(" & Str(CDbl(c)) & ",10)"
```

`CDbl`will convert the value from the locale string to the Double format, and `Str` will make a String of it using `.` as decimal separator.

You can also replace the `DecimalSeparator` directly:

```
sheet.Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(c, Application.DecimalSeparator, ".") & ",10)"
```

Comment: c was actually a number, apparently _Str(c)_ did help! Thanks!